# Django rest insert order

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am doing a small project in Django with the rest framework and I reached a point where I don't really know how to continue.

In the application, my customers can order food or drinks, which are then added to the order. I have the following models:

Orders

```
    order_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customers, on_delete = None)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

The model Customers is just a OneToOneField from the User model.

Food Orders

```
    fake_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    order_id = models.ForeignKey(Orders, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    food_id = models.ForeignKey(Food, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

Drink Orders

```
    fake_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    order_id = models.ForeignKey(Orders, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    drink_id = models.ForeignKey(Drink, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

So with my models in mind, first I need to create an order, and then create a food order or drink order for each item in the order. The problem I am having is I can't even create the order. I created a serializer and a view, pass the data with postman and nothing, I always get an error.

My serializer:

```
class OrdersSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    customer = UserSerializer()
    date = serializers.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        model = Orders

    def create(self, validated_data):
        order = Orders.objects.create(**validated_data)
        order.save()
        return order
```

My view:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def createOrder(request):
    ser = OrdersSerializer(data=request.data)

    if ser.is_valid():
        ser.save()
        return Response(ser.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response(ser._errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

This is the payload I am trying to send:

```
{
"date": [{
    "date": "2013-01-29T12:34:56.000000Z"
}],
"customer": {
    "id": [{
        "id":1
    }]
}
}
```

And this is the response I get:

```
{
"customerID": {
    "id": [
        "A valid integer is required."
    ]
},
"date": [
    "Datetime has wrong format. Use one of these formats instead: YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm[:ss[.uuuuuu]][+HH:MM|-HH:MM|Z]."
]
}
```

I feel it may be a problem with the payload, but I have really been trying to get it to work with no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your payload has an extra layer of nesting... It should be

```
{
    "date": "2013-01-29T12:34:56.000000Z",
    "customer": {
        "id":1
    }
}
```

This should be similar to the output of `ser.data`

On a side note, in case those are your actual models you might want to rename the ForeignKey fields to not have the `_id` suffix...
Django will automatically create a hidden field with `_id` (in your case `order_id_id`) which is the db field, and the field name without the `_id` suffix would be an actual model object. So in your case `order_id` would be an Order object, and not the id. This can be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The payload format is incorrect. This should be the correct format:

```
{
  "customer": { "id": 1 },
  "date": "2018-09-04 06:00:00.000000+05:30"
}
```

Also, you need to make sure that a customer with `id=1` exists in the DB.